# Google Actions Builder and Google Assistant - Looking for @sys.any equivalent intent

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, actions-builder

I have created a project for **Google Assistant** through **Google Actions Builder** (not the SDK). I successfully connect with my webhook (fulfilment), but find there is no intent similar to **@sys.any** as found in Dialogflow to allow any user response to be sent back to my webhook. Each time it triggers the NO_MATCH intent, then eventually ends the conversation.

I have designed my fulfilment robust to accommodate a range of answers, and want Actions on Google to keep sending ANY answer back to my fulfillment however I cant find an intent that allows ANY answer to trigger my webhook. Is there a simple intent (scene) to invoke each response?

Or is it a better direction to connect to Google Assistant to using Dialogflow, as I see Dialogflow uses **@sys.any** intents to capture any words for my fulfilment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be clear - `@sys.any` in Dialogflow is an Entity Type, not an Intent.

While you *can* make a Dialogflow Intent that uses `@sys.any` by itself, you usually shouldn't - using a Context-limited Fallback Intent is a better way to handle that.

Actions Builder has a similar concept, although not identical.

While there is no built-in `@sys.any` Type, you *can* create your own Type that works exactly the same way:

1. In the left navigation, expand the **Types** section and click on the **+** icon at the bottom of the expanded area.
2. Give it a name - I tend to use "Any".
3. In the Type definition, select the "Free form text" option.

You can now create Intents or Slots that use this "Any" Type.

[image: Illustration of screen described by process]

Answer (score 0):

Thanks ***Prisoner*** for pointing me in the right direction.  The *Free form text* Type did the trick once I assigned to an intent and then scene.
My information to then assign to an intent was tricky and also used this a good resource:  https://support.google.com/actions-console/answer/9802296?hl=en

After creating the "Any" type, I then created an intent called ***"UserProvidesAnything"*** and added the ***"Any"*** type as a slot. I added a training phrase such as: blah blah blah (any text really) and assigned my ***"Any"*** free form type to this phrase.

The ***"UserProvidesAnything"*** Intent was added to a Scene's Custom Intent Handling and my webhook is successfully called. Each webhook response re-activates this Scene and any text is passed back.  Thanking you